# regex find two characters with any characters between except

Tags: regex

I need a regex that can find a missing bracket.

I want to look between each pair of { {, and find only the ones that have no } between them.

I've tried

```
[\{]*[^}]*[\{]
[\{*][^}][*\{]
[\{][^}][\{]
[{]*[^}]*[{]
```

It's been five years since I've done any regex, and clearly I'm rusty.

Comment: Is that for a specific tool ? A text editor perhaps ? If so please precise it, there are different regex flavors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your question you seem to want `\{[^}]*\{`

Comment: That may work in some regex flavors (however, it will also match `{..{..{`, so not necessarily pairs of opening braces), but it's safer to escape the braces outside of character classes.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Done (it worked in my tests without the escaping). I also asked for the flavor.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Regarding the second part of your comment, it seems that it's the requirement : *"look between each pair of { {, and find only the ones that have no } between them"*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following

```
 \{[^{}]*\{
```